# getattr - Exception Value: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'model_name''

Tags: python, django, variables, getattr

I have a probleme for use a variable in model name, i want to take this command :

```
MyVar.objects.all().delete()
```

and in the same way i have to a probleme for take this :

```
class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
            class Meta:
                dbModel = MyVar
                delimiter = delimiter_csv
```

these actions are on methode of a class.
and variable is created on here methode.

Sorry for my english, i am beginner...

EDIT :

My code :

```
from etl.models import MvmtjExportTemps, MvmtjExport
from django.db import models

[...]
model_name = self.table_temporaire[self.numero_edi]
getattr(models, model_name).objects.all().delete()


class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
    class Meta:
        dbModel = getattr(models, model_name)
        delimiter = delimiter_csv
```

And i have this result :

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/etl/integration/
>
> Django Version: 1.8.18 Python Version: 3.6.1 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'pec', 
>   'topo',  'bootstrap3_datetime',  'todo_app',  'debug_toolbar',  'bi', 
>   'etl'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback: File
>   "C:\git\ATH_intranet\env_p3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>     132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "c:\git\ATH_intranet\etl\views.py" in IntegrationExtraction
>     188.                     importation.ImportationTableTemporaire(fichier) File
>   "c:\git\ATH_intranet\etl\class_perso.py" in ImportationTableTemporaire
>     112.         getattr(models, model_name).objects.all().delete()
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /etl/integration/ Exception Value:
>   module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'MvmtjExportTemps'

EDIT 2 :

Finaly i need add location in import and getattr like this :

```
import etl.models

        #vidange table temporaire
        model_name = self.table_temporaire[self.numero_edi]
        getattr(etl.models, model_name).objects.all().delete()

        # creation de la class correspondant a la table temporaire

        class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
            class Meta:
                dbModel = getattr(etl.models, model_name)
                delimiter = delimiter_csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import models 
model_name = "X"

getattr(models, model_name).objects.all().delete()

class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
            class Meta:
                dbModel = getattr(models, model_name)
                delimiter = delimiter_csv
```

Comment: i have looking for, but i have this message : No module named 'models'

Comment: so sorry u have this message module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'MvmtjExportTemps', i have been add " from app.models import *"

Comment: you should use from django.db import models

Comment: Please, I have updated my post. Do you have a last idéa for my problem?

Comment: don't use "from django.db import models". this. use "import models"

Comment: Thx, but I did this in first with message error 'No module named 'models'' and after you are told me tu put "ou should use from django.db import models"

Comment: where is your model class location 'MvmtjExportTemps' ?

Comment: in this apps models (etl app) from etl.models import MvmtjExportTemps, MvmtjExport

Comment: use "import etl.models"

Comment: thanx a lot, i have fix this error with import "import etl.models" and add location to getattr "getattr(etl.models, model_name)"